# If $R$ for a commutative ring with identity (not necessarily an integral domain) satisfies ACCP, then does $R[x]$ also have ACCP?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain, polynomial-rings

I read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249742/prove-that-if-r-is-an-integral-domain-and-has-accp-then-rx-has-accp?rq=1) that if $R$ is an integral domain and has ACCP, then $R[x]$ also has ACCP. However, is this necessarily true for a commutative ring with identity? If it is false, then what is a counterexample?

I have tried constructing a counterexample by taking $a,b \neq 0 \in R$ such that $ab=0$
e.g. they are zero divisors, and trying to construct an ascending chain of polynomial generators that increase in degree, e.g. $P_{i+1}\mid P_i$ but $\deg (P_{i+1})>\deg (P_i),$ since the argument used in the linked post used the fact that the degree must stabilize.

However, every time I increase the degree (by "dividing" by some polynomial with terms of $a$ or $b$), it seems like the exponent of $a$ and $b$ increase, leading me to think that if we start with exponent $k,$ eventually it will reach $1$ and again, the degree will stabilize.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! I think there's a counterexample [here](https://doi.org/10.2307%2F2160301). (nicer PDF [here](http://math.colgate.edu/faculty/dlantz/accp5.pdf)).

Comment: The prior linked counterexample by Heinzer and Lantz is already mentioned in the  [Wikipedia article on ACCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition_on_principal_ideals). Please search for answers before posting questions.